# SpringBoot FileWriter permission denied on production

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, filewriter

I have written a code to get the data from the database and write to a CSV file.

```
File csvOutputFile = new File(fileName);
csvOutputFile.setExecutable(true);
FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(csvOutputFile, false);
```

The code works fine on development environment but I am getting permission error on production.

This is the error population.csv (Permission denied)

```
java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method)\njava.io.FileOutputStream.open(FileOutputStream.java:270)\njava.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:213)\njava.io.FileWriter.<init>
```

I added the middle line to change the permission of the file but it is not working.

Where am I going wrong?

EDIT 1: 
these are the directory permission.

[image]

Comment: If you are using linux maybe you have to give permission for your container like tomcat to write and read in the folder.

Comment: I assume the file is written in the bin folder in the tomcat directory. The user is tomcat and it has permission.

Comment: Maybe not, you can see the user using the ls -lhat

Comment: Setting the files executable flag will not help at all. As mentioned before, the process user misses write access to the directory or file, if the file just exists. Check your assumptions ("I assume the file is written to the bin folder"), the directory and file permissions.

Comment: csvOutputFile.setWritable(true); also this wont work?

Comment: While starting the spring boot app you have to make sure that the spring boot process has write access to the directory where your trying to create/save the file. Try setting the `umask 0022` in the server startup script. This will grant 644 permission level to the any folder/file created by your app.